# Failed to precompile Plots.jl in Julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I was starting Julia code in Jupyterlab by commanding `using` so that I can use Julia packages as usual. It had been working well until this morning. Today I got this error which I do have no clue how to deal with. Please check the attached image. Any helps are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: That is weird. You could try `using Pkg; Pkg.update()` in case somehow you have an ancient version of something, somehow? Posting what `Pkg.status()` prints out might also help people to guess.

Comment: @macbbott Hi, thank you for the comment. I will try it shortly but I also think it is strange because I've been using Julia without error yesterday morning and I do not see it is an issue with old version package

Comment: @mcabbott I tried Pkd.update() and it works perfectly now! I am still not fully sure that was the reason for the error but since it works now, problem solved! Thank you so much

Comment: Did you install/update any packages before the error appeared? Some version might have changed, causing the problem. A hint is that Julia is precompiling Plots, so something changed. If so, I would try with `Pkg.resolve()` as well.

Comment: Glad it works! It's hard to guess, but sometimes when you add a package, the package manager may choose to downgrade other packages (to find a consistent solution to every package's constraints), and very occasionally this takes you to strange places.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
using Pkg; Pkg.update()
```

Credits: @mcabbott (first comment in question)

Comment: Please try to ask if the owner of the original answer will make an answer or even credit him, if you use his Intellectual property. (that's why I edited your answer). Thanks