# Failed to precompile StatsPlots.jl

Tags: julia, julia-plots

This might be connected to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853018/failed-to-precompile-plots-jl-in-julia) or [this](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/2112). However, none of the suggested solutions works for me.

I'm using VSCode with the Julia extension and I run everything in a Jupyter notebook. My first cell looks as follows.

```
using Distributions
using StatsBase
using CSV
using DataFrames
using HypothesisTests
using Plots
using GLM
using StatsPlots
```

Executing the cell yields to the following error.

```
ailed to precompile StatsPlots [f3b207a7-027a-5e70-b257-86293d7955fd] to /home/david/.julia/compiled/v1.7/StatsPlots/jl_27z7QU.

Stacktrace:
  [1] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [3] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [4] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [5] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [6] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
  [7] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1196
  [8] #invokelatest#2
    @ ./essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
  [9] invokelatest
    @ ./essentials.jl:714 [inlined]
 [10] (::VSCodeServer.var"#150#151"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:18
 [11] withpath(f::VSCodeServer.var"#150#151"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String}, path::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:185
 [12] notebook_runcell_request(conn::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, params::VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:14
 [13] dispatch_msg(x::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, dispatcher::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.MsgDispatcher, msg::Dict{String, Any})
    @ VSCodeServer.JSONRPC ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/packages/JSONRPC/src/typed.jl:67
 [14] serve_notebook(pipename::String; crashreporting_pipename::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:94
 [15] top-level scope
    @ ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.11/scripts/notebook/notebook.jl:12
```

Next, I have opened the Julia command line and removed the StatsPlots extensions using `] rm "StatsPlots"` and readded it using `] add "StatsPlots"` with no success. I have tried to execute `precompile` in the command line by hand which yields to the following output.

```
(@v1.7) pkg> precompile
Precompiling project...
  ✗ Arpack
  ✗ MultivariateStats
  ✗ StatsPlots
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 11 seconds (216 already precompiled)

ERROR: The following 1 direct dependency failed to precompile:

StatsPlots [f3b207a7-027a-5e70-b257-86293d7955fd]

Failed to precompile StatsPlots [f3b207a7-027a-5e70-b257-86293d7955fd] to /home/david/.julia/compiled/v1.7/StatsPlots/jl_1XjxNk.
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "/home/david/.julia/artifacts/cdf6dc8aa6771a61c6c65a5a5c1a8d1b75f50a2f/lib/libarpack.so"
libopenblas64_.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/products/library_generators.jl:54 [inlined]
 [2] __init__()
   @ Arpack_jll ~/.julia/packages/Arpack_jll/zfgpQ/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu-libgfortran5.jl:10
 [3] top-level scope (repeats 2 times)
   @ none:1
during initialization of module Arpack_jll
in expression starting at /home/david/.julia/packages/Arpack/pLziT/src/Arpack.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Arpack [7d9fca2a-8960-54d3-9f78-7d1dccf2cb97] to /home/david/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Arpack/jl_fCy8AR.
Stacktrace:
 [1] include(x::String)
   @ MultivariateStats ~/.julia/packages/MultivariateStats/zLpz8/src/MultivariateStats.jl:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ ~/.julia/packages/MultivariateStats/zLpz8/src/MultivariateStats.jl:113
 [3] top-level scope (repeats 2 times)
   @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/david/.julia/packages/MultivariateStats/zLpz8/src/kpca.jl:3
in expression starting at /home/david/.julia/packages/MultivariateStats/zLpz8/src/MultivariateStats.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile MultivariateStats [6f286f6a-111f-5878-ab1e-185364afe411] to /home/david/.julia/compiled/v1.7/MultivariateStats/jl_8Rrih5.
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope (repeats 2 times)
   @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/david/.julia/packages/StatsPlots/CpWiU/src/StatsPlots.jl:1
```

I have tried to restart the Julia kernel, restart VSCode, and I've tried the solution suggested in the second link that I have provided, meaning removing the package and run `gc`.

I have also removed and readded `MultivariateStats` and `Arpack` but the above error remains.

It might be from interest that it has worked before. I run into a different error first by executing the following cell.

```
@df data density(:Age, group = :Treatment, title = "Distribution of ages by treatment group", xlab = "Age", ylab="Distribution", legend=:topright)
```

The above yielded to the following error message.

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: @df not defined
```

It might have been the case that I accidently added the outdated extension `StatPlots` and that might have caused the above issue. However, I've removed the old extension and added the new one.

How can I resolve the above problem?

**Edit:** Running `Pkg.status()` yields to the following output.

```
(@v1.7) pkg> status
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.10.2
  [8f4d0f93] Conda v1.6.0
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.3.2
  [31c24e10] Distributions v0.25.48
  [38e38edf] GLM v1.6.1
  [a2cc645c] GraphPlot v0.5.0
  [86223c79] Graphs v1.6.0
  [09f84164] HypothesisTests v0.10.6
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.23.2
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.25.8
  [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.18.0
  [7f904dfe] PlutoUI v0.7.23
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.93.0
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.10.0
  [aa4a32ff] SimpleHypergraphs v0.2.0
  [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.33.14
  [f3b207a7] StatsPlots v0.14.33
```

Comment: What does `Pkg.status()` show?

Comment: I add the output to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. The root of the problem was the missing library `libopenblas64`. This could be due to a faulty Julia installation. Here is what I have done.

First, open the Julia command line and execute the following two commands.

```
using Libdl
filter!(p -> occursin("blas", p), Libdl.dllist())
```

In my case, this yielded to the following output.

```
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "/usr/bin/../lib/libblas.so"
```

I have found a similar issue in [this](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/97) Github issue. The correct hint is given there as well. Since I am using Manjaro (built on the Arch Linux operating system), there might have been a problem with the Julia installation package that I used.

I removed my Julia installation and installed the official binaries: [julia-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/julia-bin) by executing the following command.

```
yay -S julia-bin
```

Open the Julia command line again and run the first two commands. This time the output is as follows.

```
julia> filter!(p -> occursin("blas", p), Libdl.dllist())
2-element Vector{String}:
 "/usr/bin/../lib/julia/libopenblas64_.so"
 "/usr/bin/../lib/julia/libblastrampoline.so"
```

Executing my notebook works as expected now.